# What are some means that multi-party coalitions can use to ensure that they are held as accountable as possible?

Tags: democracy, government, coalition

> The literature on comparative political institutions highlights a
> tradeoff between majoritarian/plurality and proportional/consensus
> models of democracy. The former arrangement is said to enhance having
> governing parties held accountable. The latter is said to promote
> representation of a range of views, with a coalition of multiple
> parties governing. **A tradeoff may be that the representativeness of
> multi-party coalitions can make it difficult for voters to hold
> government accountable, while single-party governments that facilitate
> accountability might fail to represent a range of parties in
> government.**

https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/13540688221081783

What are some means that multi-party coalitions can use to ensure that they are held as accountable as possible? There seems to be a consensus that it is more difficult to hold multi-party coalitions accountable than single-party government. If this is indeed the case, is there anything these multi-party coalitions can do to ensure that it can still be held as accountable as a single-party government?

Comment: Reading your linked abstract to its end, it seems to me the authors are actually _challenging_ the thesis you highlight?

Comment: Why would the multiparty coalition *want* to be held accountable?  Being held accountable means "if you make mistakes the electorate can easily replace you with your opponents"  Why would a government want to make it easy for the electorate to remove them?